# Is it possible to install Burp Suite via apt or snap?

Tags: apt, snap

As for now, the only way that I know to install Burp by downloading the binary and install it on your machine.

https://portswigger.net/burp/releases/community/latest

https://portswigger.net/burp/releases/professional-community-2021-6-2?requestededition=community

Is it possible to install Burp Suite via apt or snap?

Comment: It does not seem to be a free software. Unless they decide to release it as apt or snap, we cannot do anything.

Comment: You can ask their support channel to provide a snap package or apt repository.

Comment: @ArchismanPanigrahi There is a community edition for burp suite. See https://portswigger.net/burp/communitydownload